# Express a parametrization of a curve $C$ as a function of $X$ and $Y$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Express the curve $C$ with parametrization $\{(\cos 3t, \sin 2t) : t \in \mathbb{R} \}$ as a function of $X$ and $Y$.

Here's what I have (I don't know if this is helpful)

I let $X= \cos 3t$ and $Y= \sin 2t$. So I have $X= \cos^3 t -3\sin^2 t \cos t$ and $Y=2 \cos t \sin t$.

I don't know how to go on from here. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: As a set of points, $C$ isn't a function from $\mathbb R$ tp $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer**:
$$
X^4 - X^2 + 4 Y^6 - 6 Y^4 + \frac{9}{4} Y^2 = 0
$$

**How I got it**:

We can replace the trigonometric parametrization $(\cos(u), \sin(u))$ of the unit circle with a rational one: $\left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, \frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)$. So we equate $\cos(u) = x = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ and $\sin(u) = y =\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$. Your expressions for $X$ and $Y$ then become
\begin{align*}
X &= \cos^3(u) - 3 \cos(u) \sin^2(u) = x^3 - 3 xy^2 = \frac{-t^{6} + 15 t^{4} - 15 t^{2} + 1}{(1+t^2)^3}\\
Y &= 2 \cos(u) \sin(u) = 2 x y = \frac{-4 t^{3} + 4 t}{(1+t^2)^2}
\end{align*}

In the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Q}[t,z,X,Y]$ we form the ideal
$$
I = ((1+t^2)^3 X -(-t^{6} + 15 t^{4} - 15 t^{2} + 1), (1+t^2)^2 Y - (-4 t^{3} + 4 t), (1+t^2)z - 1)
$$
and compute a Gröbner basis with respect to the elimination ordering $t > z > X > Y$. The last entry of this Gröbner basis is the desired polynomial in $X$ and $Y$.

The proof is in the pudding, though: [here is a SageMathCell comparing the two plots](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJw9jUEKgzAQRfeCd5idExtpTEXahVdRRAodUBOSwcbbd0JpV__9gXn_mANWXKmyiC_3Rj-HeXtyoGXyq2PExUW81aw0RNrRCgkia6Nt7UkpeSyLI0uSPv8a2vxKC_FXksYOGkijhQt09Tn20nrJTvrjmi8WhgGMiJNuWt3mifNHWTF5RzvH4W6MUh81-jGm&lang=sage).

Actually, a slightly better way is to instead compute a Gröbner basis for the ideal $(X - (x^3 - 3xy^2), Y - (2xy), x^2 + y^2 - 1)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y,X,Y]$ with respect to the elimination ordering $x > y > X > Y$. This yields the same answer.

Comment: Another way to get rid of fractions is to homogenize to `I=ideal(X-(-t^6+15*t^4*u^2-15*t^2*u^4+u^6),Y-(-4*t^3*u+4*t*u^3)*(t^2+u^2),Z-(t^2+u^2)^3)` and after taking the gröbner basis, set $Z=1$ in the resulting $16Y^6+4X^4Z^2-24Y^4Z^2-4X^2Z^4+9Y^2Z^4$. (+1)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! However, we haven't encounterer Gröbner basis yet. Do you think there is still another way to get it without using Gröbner basis?

Comment: @MashedPotato Have you learned other tools from elimination theory? It is probably possible to do this with resultants instead of Gröbner bases. A more brute-force approach might also be possible. From a plot of the parametrization, we can see that the curve has degree $6$ (a generic line intersects it in $6$ points). So we write down a degree $6$ polynomial with $28$ undetermined coefficients. We can impose linear conditions conditions on these coefficients by plugging in points we obtain by substituting various values of $t$ into the parametrization, e.g., $t=0$ says $(1,0)$ lies on $C$.

Comment: You can also plug the parametrization directly into the degree $6$ polynomial in $X$ and $Y$ and get linear relations that way. But this naïve method seems quite hard and tedious! The thing is, once you have a proposed answer, it's easy to check by substituting in the parametrization and seeing that the equation holds.

Comment: I'm only taking an introductory course so I think what will really work for me are the brute force methods. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Hello! I've discovered a way to solve this without using Gröbner basis. I'll try to type it here if I have time since it's quite long. I just used half angle identities and plugged it in the equation. It worked.